# why 18.04 malloc.h does not have mallinfo?

Tags: compiling, gcc

The following code doesn't compile:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   struct mallinfo mi;

   mi = mallinfo();

    return 0;
}
```

```bsh
~/ssd/tmp$ gcc t.c
t.c: In function ‘main’:
t.c:8:20: error: storage size of ‘mi’ isn’t known
    struct mallinfo mi;
                    ^~
t.c:10:9: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘mallinfo’; did you mean ‘main’? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    mi = mallinfo();
         ^~~~~~~~
         main
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this - do you perhaps have a non-standard version of `malloc.h` somewhere ahead of `/usr/include/malloc.h` in the compiler's include path (such as `/usr/local/include`)?

Comment: you are right! there is a malloc.h inside /usr/local/include from other package. I removed it and it is working now. Thanks!

Comment: @user952790 You can add that as an answer and mark it as accepted after 48 hours of posting the question. Thanks :)